# Don't want to run if statement forever

Tags: python, django

I am writing an app in Django. There is one requirement that 1st 10 users will get off on their 1st purchase. And the money deduction is written in cron.So no user input.

What can i do here is that maintain column in db like used(boolean) and check if used or not.

But at some point of time lets say 1 month and assuming that all 1st 10 users have purchased something the code still going to check every time this condition.

Assuming that my app gonna run like forever, I was thinking that is there a way to implement this so that i don't have to write if.

e.g models.py

```
class User(something):
    ....
    user = something.Boolean()
```

tasks.py

```
def x():
    users = User....all()
    for user in users:
        if user in 1st 10 and not user.used:
            charge(100)
        else:
            charge(150)
```

After some time every user in 1st 10 has used its promo.
So i want to remove that ugly if statement so my func x is:

```
def x():
    users = User....all()
    for user in users:
        charge(150)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

If you want to get the first 10 users without the `used` flag set, then you should do so, instead of getting all users:

```
users = User.objects.filter(used=False)[:10]
```

Comment: Whilst correct, this doesn't really guarantee the "first" 10, that would be down to the OP's ordering choice

Comment: No, I want to get all the users but only 1 st 10 has special previlage once.After that they are normal user like everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

If the point there is to avoid if statement because it's ugly - you cannot do so, I suggest you place [TODO Codetag](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0350/#what-are-codetags) for removing useless if statement.

If you are fine with if statement but want to gain in performance you can override your function  in runtime after ensuring that `if user in 1st 10 and not user.used` is never evaluated to `True`, see simplified override below:

```
def new_x():
    print 3


def x():
    print 2
    global x
    x = new_x


x() # 2
new_x() # 3
x() # 3
```